# Is it possible, to animate bunch of text paragraphs appear disappear in specific order using just CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: css, html

I need to display a text for limited time and thereafter another text in the same place and so on, **No Moving** just **Appearance** and **Disappearance** of all timely texts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<style> 
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */@-webkit-keyframes example {from {background-color:
red;}to {background-color: yellow;}}
/* Standard syntax */@keyframes example {from {}to {background-color:
yellow;}}
</style></head>
<body>
<div style="width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: black;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 3s;">1st Text</div>
<script>
var i=1;
while(i<7){document.write("d");i++;}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? How is your html structured? Have you used CSS animations before? Have you considered the accessibility of what you are asking to do?

Comment: I tried CSS time function, my HTML structure is standard/normal, Yess but for moving text. Is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible with just CSS to animate a stack of items similar to a stack of flashcards. However it would be much more complex to do so in a way that would be workable for someone who was using a screen reader. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: For the Q&A format we use here, we need to preserve questions as they were asked. So, if you have an answer, please add it below, rather than overwriting the question. You can find the answer you pasted by looking at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48920699/revisions). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I include a live sample that i think does what you need.

```js
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        if (typeof wrapper.classList !== 'undefined') {
            wrapper.classList.add('slide-items');
        }
        else {
            var curentclass = wrapper.className;
            currentclass += ' slide-items';
            wrapper.className = currentclass;
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper > p {
    padding: 12px 7px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.delay1 {
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.delay2 {
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}

.delay3 {
    transition-delay: 1.8s;
}

.delay4 {
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}

.wrapper.slide-items-in-from-bottom > p {
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.wrapper.slide-items > p {
   opacity: 1;
   -ms-transform: none;
   -webkit-transform: none;
   transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper slide-items-in-from-bottom" id="wrapper">
    <p>This is paragraph one</p>
    <p class="delay1">This is paragraph two</p>
    <p class="delay2">this is paragraph three</p>
    <p class="delay3">this is paragraph four</p>
</div>
```

Comment: to make them dissappear, you can set another timeout and remove the class "slide-items" from the parent wrapper div. you can even remove the elements from the dom once they have dissappeared. it all boils down to your need. you can make it a loop too and you could listen for scroll event instead of setting timeout too.

Comment: Thanks for the help!